# How to configure graphic to show only points from my data set?

Tags: dygraphs

For example:

### Initial states:

I have set data:
`{1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5}`
In the initial graphic there are shown points with values:
`{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

### Action:

Trying to zoom some point between 2 and 3.

### What is actually is happening:

it zooms and new coordinates are:
`{2 2.3 2.5 2.8 3}`

### What I want:

I want from graphic to be shown only points which are persistent in my initially specified data set:
`{2 2.5 3}`
Points **2.3** and **2.8** are excluded (not shown in x axis).

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Yervand

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. Please provide an example link via http://dygraphs.com/fiddle to illustrate what the problem is.

Comment: He's saying that he doesn't like the automatic granularity of the X axis upon zooming. He has a dataset that has equally-spaced x coordinates and he want's the vertical gridlines to not interpolate, to never wind up between data points.